# Sign in via Google Plus APIs

Tags: authentication, google-plus, access-token

I am trying to collect data of my user while he signs up for my website.

I am asking for the following scopes while making a request

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="1085488274737.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

Then I am first trying to get the email ID and google plus ID of the user by making a GET request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=` with the access token obtained in the previous step. This works perfectly fine. It gives me ID and email of user.

However, if I am using that ID obtained and the access token to get the further profile details and the friends in his circle, it is not working.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userID/?key=
```

It says invalid key Invalid.

I am totally clueless because of this . Is there any error in mentioning the data-scope ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing the `/plus/v1/people/{userID}` call, you can either specify the `key` or the `access_token`, and use the corresponding parameter. If you specify the key, this should be the application key that has been assigned to you in the API Console. If you use the access_token, you can use the access token that you have received as part of the Sign-In button process.

Since you have it, it seems best to use the access_token something like this:

> https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=11111111111111111111111

Comment: Sometimes you just have a brain-o and it takes someone else to point it out. Better than continuously beating your head against a wall!

Comment: If you set the userid to "me", you must use the access token and not a key. In general, you'll always have more luck with an access token. API keys are limited in what they will be able to access.

Ideally, use a client library to handle the API requests for you, it will reduce headaches significantly.